# Why do we need (radioButton != null) for checking the value of radioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, android-view

While reading following code i found 
if statement containing

```
radioButton != view
```

### I have 2 doubts

First , isnt it radioButton is a view 
Second , what is the requrement of having this check in the code

```
public RadioButton getSelectedRadio(View view) {
    RadioButton [] btns = {centerBtn,centerCropBtn,centerInsideBtn,fitCenterBtn,
      fitEndBtn,fitStartBtn,fitXYBtn,matrixBtn, noneBtn};
    for (RadioButton radioButton : btns) {
        if (radioButton.isChecked() && radioButton != view) {
            return radioButton;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: radio button is view for android and we need to check whether view is available or not , that why it all check

Comment: in code there is if statement if (radioButton.isChecked() && radioButton != view) here we are saying radioButton != view , if view is available then it should not allow it to get inside the if statement isnt that wrong

Comment: if statement should be like this if (radioButton.isChecked() && radioButton != null) ,

Comment: Thanks @Janku i got this now , actually logic is that if the view is not equal to the newly selected radiobutton then it sets that radio button as false , i.e. the previous radio button will be unchecked 
Thanks for the help though